# Should there be a LEGO logo inside SW Clone Trooper helmet?

Tags: piece-information, minifigures, star-wars

Should the [Clone Trooper (sw0541)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw0541) [helmet](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11217pb09)  have any LEGO markings inside proving its authenticity?
I have one without any marking inside. Is it original or not?

[image]

Comment: Normally, both the logo and part number are on the inside of helmets. I don't have that specific one to check where it is. Typically either inside the stud recess, or on the ring around the stud recess. They're often hard to discern, but some direct light shone into the helmet can help.